# Easiest way to access Postgress Database from Windows Machine?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres database on a linux server. I have root access which in turn can give me access to the database. In Windows you get PGAdminIII, which I would love to use to connect to the Linux server. I heard that tunneling might be necessary. I am not sure if that is true, or what it is really. Can anyone shed some light on the easiest way to get access to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Tunneling is not strictly necessary. As long as you have port 5432 not firewalled, you should be able to connect to your Linux PostgreSQL server without much trouble.

You can check this from your Windows box by using this command from cmd console:

```
telnet linuxbox 5432
```

If you get black screen (not an error), then everything looks good and port 5432 should be open. Note that on Windows 7 you may need to enable `telnet` client (it is disabled by default) using this command:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

If your server is not located in your local network, or if you are concerned about security like somebody using network sniffer to watch your traffic, you should configure SSL/TLS on your PostgreSQL server - it is not very difficult to do, and completely free when using self-signed certificate.

Note that by default Postgres on Linux does not listen on network interfaces, you may need to enable it by editing `postgresql.conf`.